# Getting a value from a ObjectList

Tags: java, spring, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have defined this query in a JPA Repository

```
 @org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query("select min(cur.volumeUsd24h), max(cur.volumeUsd24h), "
        + "min(marketCapUsd),       max(marketCapUsd), "
        + "min(availableTickets),   max(availableTickets), "
        + "min(totalTickets),       max(totalTickets),  "
        + "min(maxTickets),         max(maxTickets)  "
        + "from Tickets cur  ")
  Object findQueryFiltersValues ();
```

and

```
Object filtersValues = tdkService.findQueryFiltersValues();

if (LOG.isDebugEnabled()) {
    LOG.debug("filtersValues {} " , filtersValues.getClass());
}
```

where:

```
filtersValues class [Ljava.lang.Object;
```

where I clearly see that the class is  `[Ljava.lang.Object;` , but I don't know how to get the different elements of the list because if I do

```
LOG.debug("filtersValues {} " , filtersValues[0]);
```

I got a compilation error:

```
The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to 
 Object
```

and when I log `LOG.debug(filtersValues.getClass().isArray());` is `true`

I also tried with

```
 @org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query("select min(cur.volumeUsd24h), max(cur.volumeUsd24h), "
        + "min(marketCapUsd),       max(marketCapUsd), "
        + "min(availableTickets),   max(availableTickets), "
        + "min(totalTickets),       max(totalTickets),  "
        + "min(maxTickets),         max(maxTickets)  "
        + "from Tickets cur  ")
  List<Object> findQueryFiltersValues ();
```

and then

```
List<Object> filtersValues = tdkService.findQueryFiltersValues();

List<Object> ret = Arrays.asList(filtersValues);

List<Object> values = Arrays.asList(ret);


Long value =  (Long)values.get(0);
```

but then I got

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.Arrays$ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.Long
```

Comment: did you tried this: List<Object> findQueryFiltersValues ();

Comment: Use `Arrays.toString(filtersValues )` if you want to log that array.

Comment: The method toString(long[]) in the type Arrays is not applicable for the arguments 
 (Object)   :-(

Comment: Please add `LOG.debug(filtersValues.getClass().isArray());` line, but if it is not an array then why `Object[] filtersValues = tdkService.findQueryFiltersValues();` doesn't throw error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don't you map the result directly to domain object?

Example:

```
@Query("SELECT new com.test.project.model.SimpleObjectStatisticsModel(MIN(cur.volumeUsd24h), MAX(cur.volumeUsd24h)," +
            "MIN(marketCapUsd), MAX(marketCapUsd),MIN(availableTickets), MAX(availableTickets), MIN(totalTickets), MAX(totalTickets)," +
            "MIN(maxTickets), MAX(maxTickets)) FROM Tickets cur")
List<SimpleObjectStatisticsModel> findQueryFiltersValues();
```

And create some domain object `com.test.project.model.SimpleObjectStatisticsModel` with all arguments constructor.

Version:

```
def springDataVersion = '1.11.4.RELEASE'
```

Answer (score 1):

If your repository method is defined as `Object findQueryFiltersValues()` the following should work.

```
if (filtersValues.getClass().isArray()) {
    Object[] filtersValuesArray = (Object[])filtersValues;
    // if you want a list continue like this:
    List<Object> filtersValuesList = Arrays.asList(filtersValuesArray);
} else {
    log.debug("not an array");
}
```

Here is why your code isn't working:

```
filtersValues[0]
```

requires an array at compile time, but at compile time the only knowledge the compiler has is that it is an `Object`.

There are actually two ways to interpret

```
Arrays.asList(filtersValues)
```

1. call `asList` with a single argument of type `Object` and make a `List` out of it with that single element.
2. call `asList` with a single argument of type `Object[]` and make a `List` out of it which contains all the elements of the array. 
   The decision which to use is made at compile time. 
   Again the compiler doesn't know that the argument is an array so the compiler chooses the first variant and in your case puts a `List` into a `List`.

In my variant, the compiler knows the argument is an array and chooses the second variant.

If your query always returns `Long`s then you can define your method as

```
List<Long> findQueryFiltersValues();
```

without any further need of conversion.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ArrayList list = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(filtersValues); 
Long value =  (Long)list.get(0);
```